# Is there any way to generate year column from existing column names in R?

Tags: r, time-series, reshape

I am working with a dataset that has the corresponding year attached to variable names as suffix, e.g. AXOX1991, where AXO is the variable. I am trying to separate the year from the variable label/column names to generate a year column so that the dataset can be analyzed as time-series data.

In other words, the existing dataset looks like:

| Country | AXOX1991 | AXOX1992 | BXOX1991 | BXOX1992 | CXOX1991 | CXOX1992 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| USA | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

And I am trying to create the following:

| Country | Year | AXO | BXO | CXO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1991 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| Afghanistan | 1992 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| USA | 1991 | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| USA | 1992 | 5 | 3 | 1 |

As you can see, X not only acts as the delimiter that divides the variable name and the year, but it is also part of the variable name.  Is there any way in R to separate the year from the variable name in existing column names and then to create a year column as shown above?

I have been thinking of workarounds, such as loops, but I haven't gotten very far, and I'm truly stumped. I have more than 900 variable-years, so I want to avoid doing it by hand if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `tidyr::pivot_longer` -

```
res <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -Country, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'Year'), 
                    names_pattern = '([A-Z]+)X(\\d+)')
res

#  Country     Year    AXO   BXO   CXO
#  <chr>       <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Afghanistan 1991      1     3     5
#2 Afghanistan 1992      2     4     6
#3 USA         1991      6     4     2
#4 USA         1992      5     3     1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "USA"), AXOX1991 = c(1L, 
6L), AXOX1992 = c(2L, 5L), BXOX1991 = 3:4, BXOX1992 = 4:3, CXOX1991 = c(5L, 
2L), CXOX1992 = c(6L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I made a mistake in my question, and I have since updated it. The variable names **also** contain X —  is there a way for me to substitute the variable names such that this method could work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make use of `names_pattern` to specify the regex pattern in the column name. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution using `melt()` with the new `measure()` function (introduced with `data.table`  v1.14.1):

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.1
melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = measure(value.name, year, 
                                       pattern = "(\\w{3})X(\\d{4})"))
```

> ```
>        Country year AXO BXO CXO
> 1: Afghanistan 1991   1   3   5
> 2:         USA 1991   6   4   2
> 3: Afghanistan 1992   2   4   6
> 4:         USA 1992   5   3   1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("Country    AXOX1991    AXOX1992    BXOX1991    BXOX1992    CXOX1991    CXOX1992
Afghanistan 1   2   3   4   5   6
USA 6   5   4   3   2   1")
```